# how to use parent argument in Apollo GraphQL Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, apollo-server

Resolver functions are passed four arguments: parent, args, contextValue.
I use args and contextValue argument for API.
But I can't understand how to use parent argument in resolver function.

When do I use parent argument in Apollo GraphQL? Please explain about this.